# jsp: collect all selected checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am new to jQuery and jsp, jstl, sorry for this probably trivial question. I have following code in jsp:

```
  <ct:thead>
    <ct:th>
      <ct:checkbox styleClass="toggleCheckbox"/>
    </ct:th>
    <ct:th><ct:message messageKey="documentID"/></ct:th>
```

rendered html is following:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="checkboxGroup">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
        <input name="documentID" type="hidden" value="6">
    </td>
    <td>6</td>
```

I would like to collect all `documentID`s that selected using jQuery. How would it look like? Thanks in advance!

Comment: share the rendered html output

Comment: please send your full code in order to review it.

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I added rendered html. Please, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select based on name attribute value.

```
$('[name="documentID"]')
```

```js
$('[name="documentID"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="checkboxGroup">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
      <input name="documentID" type="hidden" value="6">
    </td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```